# Fast way to check if a specific computer exists in my network

Tags: vb6, network-programming

Well... I think the title says all. I wanna check if a pc exists on my network, for example "JOAN-PC".

Now I'm doing something like this:

```
Dim oShell As Object
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
MsgBox Not CBool(oShell.NameSpace(CVar("\\JOAN-PC")) Is Nothing)
```

Works good, but is slow, and my program have to call it a lot of times.
Some of you know a fast way to do the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does your program have to call it a lot of times? Are you really expecting computers to appear/disappear at rapid rates that can't be handled by your existing solution?

Comment: I have to check it every second becouse my program is copying files to a shared folder. And before this I need to make sure that the PC is connected by LAN and its folder is available. I want to consume the least possible resources, that's all.

Comment: You don't need to check it at all. You need to do the copy and handle the error conditions that can result. You have to handle them anyway. At the moment you're trying to predict that the operation can succeed. This is fortune-telling, not computing. The only reliable way to tell that a resource is available is to try to use it.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this. Really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `NetRemoteTOD` or a related simple network API, even a "ping" request.

Here's a small example you might adapt.  Give it a try, the timeout for machines that don't respond doesn't seem too long (7 or 8 seconds).  For legit uses this probably won't be an issue, but it is long enough to discourage malicious "scanners" trying to sweep whole networks by IP address for victim machines.

```
Option Explicit

'Fetch and display Net Remote Time Of Day from a
'remote Windows system.  Supply a UNC hostname,
'DNS name, or IP address - or empty string for
'the local host's time and date.
'
'Form has 3 controls:
'
'   txtServer   TextBox
'   cmdGetTime  CommandButton
'   lblTime     Label

Private Const NERR_SUCCESS As Long = 0

Private Type TIME_OF_DAY_INFO
    tod_elapsedt As Long
    tod_msecs As Long
    tod_hours As Long
    tod_mins As Long
    tod_secs As Long
    tod_hunds As Long
    tod_timezone As Long
    tod_tinterval As Long
    tod_day As Long
    tod_month As Long
    tod_year As Long
    tod_weekday As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function NetApiBufferFree Lib "netapi32" ( _
    ByVal lpBuffer As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function NetRemoteTOD Lib "netapi32" ( _
    ByRef UncServerName As Byte, _
    ByRef BufferPtr As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef pTo As Any, _
    ByRef uFrom As Any, _
    ByVal lSize As Long)

Private Function GetTOD(ByVal Server As String) As Date
    Dim bytServer() As Byte
    Dim lngBufPtr As Long
    Dim todReturned As TIME_OF_DAY_INFO

    bytServer = Trim$(Server) & vbNullChar
    If NetRemoteTOD(bytServer(0), lngBufPtr) = NERR_SUCCESS Then
        CopyMemory todReturned, ByVal lngBufPtr, LenB(todReturned)
        NetApiBufferFree lngBufPtr
        With todReturned
            GetTOD = DateAdd("n", _
                             -.tod_timezone, _
                             DateSerial(.tod_year, .tod_month, .tod_day) _
                           + TimeSerial(.tod_hours, .tod_mins, .tod_secs))
        End With
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError Or &H2000&, _
                  "GetTOD", _
                  "Failed to obtain time from server"
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmdGetTime_Click()
    Dim dtServerTime As Date

    On Error Resume Next
    dtServerTime = GetTOD(txtServer.Text)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        lblTime.Caption = Err.Description
    Else
        lblTime.Caption = CStr(dtServerTime)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    txtServer.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect you're done then.  NetGetJoinInformation and other calls in this family are subject to the same issues.  Even ICMP pings aren't reliable without waiting some interval for replies.

Comment: Oh! NetGetJoinInformation() api works perfectly, and is faster than my method. Really thanks Bob77!